# Do I need to install any additional libbraries for Android 2.3 to fully support all JavaFx graphics, gui?

Tags: android, javafx

If I need to develop JavaFx application with rich user interface (3D shapes ... etc) then Do I have to install some kind of libraries on my android 2.3 device to fully support JavaFx features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX is not supported on Android ATM.

Answer (score 0):

Still RnD on this is going on, Some People are doing great job on this and some how they got success with some specific platform but still not produces any stable version to the market.

please go through below links to flow up,

1) https://blogs.oracle.com/jfxprg/entry/javafx_on_android
2) https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Cross+Building+for+Android